# 'shuterstock_init' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Tags: typescript

I have service `class imageService` with mosty key value pairs

```
export type servicesName = "unsplash" | "pexels" | "pixabay" | 'shutterstock';

export type Service = {
  [key in servicesName]?: string;

};
```

and

```
class ImageServices {
  services: Service;
  constructor(services: Service) {
    // creating key-value pair, key -> name of service, value api key (easy to access)
    this.services = { ...services };
  }
// code
```

Now, Shutterstock actually gives cosumer_key and consumer_secret instead of just api_key. I want this to reflect in my type i.e if key is shutterstock, then it would be object with consumer_key and consume_secret so I did something like this

```
interface shuterstock_init {
  consumer_id: string
  consumer_secret: string
}


export type Service = {
  [key in servicesName]?: string;
  shutterstock?: shuterstock_init
};
```

but this is throwing following error

```
'}' expected.ts(1005)
Cannot find name 'shutterstock'.
```

and

```
'shuterstock_init' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here
```

Can someone help me in fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I did this and it worked

```
interface Service {
  unsplash?: string;
  pexels?: string;
  pixabay?: string;
  shutterstock?: shuterstock_init
};
```